# OpenMP First function call is slow

Tags: c, openmp, cpython

A parallelized function in C is slow on the first call. The subsequent call exectues ~5x faster.
The number of calculations is exactly the same.

The heavy lifting is done by this function which has two subsequent calls from the outer loop. This outer loop repeats >10k times. Always the first call is slow.

```c
#pragma omp parallel private(ishift, iarray, i, istart, weight) num_threads(nparallel)
{
#pragma omp for schedule(dynamic, chunk) nowait
for (ishift=0; ishift<(int32_t)nshifts; ishift++) {
    for (iarray=0; iarray<narrays; iarray++) {
        weight = weights[ishift*narrays + iarray];
        if (weight == 0.0)
            continue;
        istart = offsets[iarray] + shifts[ishift*narrays + iarray];
        #pragma omp simd
        for (i=(size_t)i32max(0, imin - istart); i<(size_t)i32max(0, i32min(nsamp - istart + imin, lengths[iarray])); i++) {
            result[ishift*nsamp + istart-imin+i] += arrays[iarray][i] * weight;
        }
    }
}
}
```

The `result` is ~ 2-4 GB in size, also `arrays` is very large.

The shear size of the data does not fit into caches, so cold caches cannot explain the behavior.

I have played around with `OMP_WAIT_POLICY` and other OpenMP runtime variables but none could explain the big discrapancy.

### Solution

Re-filling `result` with zeros, instead of a new `calloc` keeps the buffers hot and the first call will be as fast as the second one.

Comment: I can be due to many things. It is hard to tell without platforms information (OS and CPU). The most probable effect is page faults : if `result` is not physically mapped, then the OS will map it on the fly. This is expensive. Once mapped, there is no overhead. You can check that by filling `result` with some values (not zeros if possible). I assume input arrays are manually initialized (and not zero initialized using functions like `calloc`).

Comment: Another less probable effect is the remapping of pages on NUMA nodes on NUMA platforms. This is why the actual CPU used matters.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mapping overhead. When `result` is cached and re-filled with zeros the mapping stays hot.

Comment: Another possibility is that this is the first parallel region executed in the program, so the first call includes the time to create the thread team.